# Google Cloud SDK Python Client: How to list files inside of a Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Trying to use Python to get and iterate through all of the files inside of a Cloud Storage bucket I own. I'm using the official library, `google-cloud-storage`.

Using `gsutil`, I can run commands like `gsutil ls gs://my-composer-bucket/dags/composer_utils/`. Does the `google-cloud-storage` library offer an equivalent method to `gsutil ls`? I'd like to use the Python client rather than shell out to `gsutil` (don't want to install and authenticate the GCloud SDK inside of a Docker image).

I've tried a few different things which have left me confused on how blobs work:

```
>>> dag_folder_blob = cloud_composer_bucket.blob(bucket, 'dags/')
>>> dag_folder_blob.exists()
True
>>> util_folder_blob = cloud_composer_bucket.blob(bucket, 'dags/composer_utils/')  # directory exists
>>> util_folder_blob.exists()
False
>>> util_file_blob = cloud_composer-bucket.blob(bucket, 'dags/composer_utils/__init__.py')
>>> util_file_blob.exists()
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the [list_blobs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.list_blobs) method of a Bucket object.  Read more about [listing objects in Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects).

Comment: Thank you! Didn't consider that it might've been an operation related to the Bucket object, though I know Cloud Storage doesn't have "directories" in the local filesystem sense.

Comment: You're right, there's no directories.  What you're doing with the list API is "searching" all the blobs in the bucket that match the pattern you specify.

Answer (score 1):

```
# replicating command: gsutil ls gs://<bucketName>/<prefix>

from google.cloud import storage
bucket = storage.Client(<proj>).bucket(<bucketName>)
for key in bucket.list_blobs(prefix=<prefix>):
    print key
```